# Populate Gender and Date of Birth fields based on ID number field

Tags: javascript

I'd like to use JavaScript to populate Gender and Date of Birth fields based on ID number field. The ID number is the [South African National ID number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identification_number#South_Africa).

For example, the below ID number

> 6107310094082

Should be breakdown into:

- 610731 = date of birth
- 0 = gender, any number between 0-4 is Female and number between 5-9 is Male
- 094 = sequence number registered with same date of birth
- 0 = citizenship
- 82 = checksum

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use JavaScript for this instead of Java? Why not just letting Java (JSP? JSF?) produce the right HTML output from beginning on? Regardless, this is just a matter of splitting and/or substringing the string.

Comment: It was just a personal choice. How can i asplit the string?

Comment: Start here: http://htmldog.com/guides/javascript

Comment: this looks like a basic substring operation try to google it. or see this [MDN doc here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) . You will find many example similar to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript to perform it like this:

```
var code = '6107310094082',
personDetails = {'dob': '', 'isMale' : '', 'citizenship' : ''},
strlenth = (code.length-1);

for (var i=0;i<strlenth;i++){
    if(i<(strlenth-6)){
        personDetails.dob += code[i];
    } else if (i == 6){
        personDetails.isMale = ((code[i] > 4) ? true : false);
    } else if(i == 10){
        personDetails.citizenship += code[i];
    }
}

console.log(personDetails);
//output: Object {dob: "610731", isMale: false, citizenship: "0"}
```